# Can't connect to a computer on network running a server in java from my app

Tags: android, client

I am trying to connect a simple android client to a simple java server on another computer running on the same wi-fi network, i was able to connect with a java code(non android) on eclipse, and the server works just fine, but when i take the same code and put in my android app (android studio), it throws an IOException.
As of right now my protocol just returns a string "yay" and i just want to display it in a View.

My code:

```
       private void createCom2(TextView showResult){
    Socket pazeSocket = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String ip = "10.0.0.4";

    try {
        pazeSocket = new Socket(ip, 4444);
        pw = new PrintWriter(pazeSocket.getOutputStream());
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pazeSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Don't know about host: " + ip , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + ip , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: in the catchblock for the IOException try `log.e("IOException", e.getMessage()`and post the result.

Comment: socket failed eacces (permission denied)

Comment: does your app have internet permission?

Comment: permissions? of course
please post an answer, ill mark it as right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Internet permission for your app. Add this line to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and read more abut permissions here, if you like:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html